# How to define my string and type of encoding. NSString -NSSdata

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdata, http-request

I am trying to post a string with 2 values to a URL. To define my string I am using:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"...."];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding: .... allowLossyConversion: NO];
```

The string I want to post is this one: `geoX#value #geoY#value`.
How do I add this string in my NSString command and what type of dataUsingEncoding should I use?

Also at the command:

```
[request setValue:@"....." forHTTPHeaderField:"...."]
```

What value do I add and what type of content if header -->content-type :text/html?

Comment: I believe you would be alright we `NSUTF8Encoding`.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response. Any idea of how to define my request setValue command if my content-type is text/html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the values stored in two variables as follows,

```
NSString *geoXValue = @"1.2343243";
NSString *geoYValue = @"1.5646546";
```

This is how you need to append the values to string,

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"geoX%@ geoY%@", geoXValue, geoYValue];
```

To convert this to data, you can use the following line,

```
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
```

And to set the content-type in header, try this,

```
[request setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type"]
```

Hope it is clear now.

Comment: THanks a lot.I had already found a solution there but u helped me into another problme i had.